# Does autocorrelation at granular intervals still exist at aggregated intervals?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive, aggregation

I have a theoretical question autocorrelation at different sized intervals. Suppose I have a dataset at minutely intervals, that follows an AR(2) process and then drops into white noise at lags > 2. If I were to then aggregate by taking the final reading at annual intervals. Would this minutely autocorrelation relationship still persist into annual intervals or would it not have an impact? In other words, do relationships at finer intervals propagate at larger intervals?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If autocorrelation is due to a high-frequency AR process (in contrast to an MA process*), then it will be found in the corresponding low-frequency aggregate process as well. If the autocorrelation is decreasing with lag length in high-frequency data, it will be small in low-frequency data. You can see both things by writing down the algebraic expressions of an aggregate low-frequency process of a high-frequency AR process. Alternatively, you can simulate the high-frequency process, obtain its low-frequency aggregate and inspect its autocorrelation function.

*Autocorrelation generated by a high-frequency MA process will disappear if the frequency of the aggregate process is low enough.